# Does .net stop checking the rest of an IF statement if you use an and/or ( || / && )?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, if-statement

say you have something like:

int num = 0

then you do

```
if(num > 5 || num < 4)
{
  ...
}
```

it checks both, but what if you do

```
if(num < 4 || num > 5)
{
  ...
}
```

does it only check the 1st statement?
same as:

```
if(num > 5 && num == 0)
{
  ...
}
```

it should stop after failing the 1st and... right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [**boolean short-circuit evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and (although <sup>`[citation-needed]`</sup>) yes, C# and VB.NET have it (thanks [@Lasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) for the correction).

In C#, [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) are the short-circuited versions of [`|`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) and [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx), respectively
.

Comment: You mean C# and VB.NET has that (and other programming languages as well), .NET doesn't have anything to say in the matter.

Comment: +1 but thought I'd add:  Exceptions to this rule are And and Or in VB.  To short-circuit, use AndAlso/OrElse instead.

Comment: Thanks @Lasse, I don't visit the .NET world terribly often.

Comment: Wait, what do the `&&` and `||` operators have to do with `&` and `|`? The former are Logical operators that operate on `bool`s and short-circuit, while the latter are bitwise operators that operate on numbers and don't short-circuit because that doesn't make sense (and, you can't use them on `bool`s either)

Comment: @Mike `|` and `&` operates on `bool`s as well - and they don't short-circuit.

Comment: yeah, i'm using it in C#, but didn't think they're would have been a difference for VB.NET.  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this feature is called short circuit evaluation. If the first argument to the AND operator (`&&`) is false, then the entire expression will be false. Similarly with OR (`||`) if the first operand in true, the entire thing is true.

This feature is useful if you want to write the code similar to:

```
    if(a != null && a.isValid())
        ... Code ...
```

This way you are not going to get an exception if `a` is null.

MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Good example with the point about not having to worry about a null reference by doing the null check first.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it right, yes. Take a look here: http://devpinoy.org/blogs/nocampo/archive/2007/09/28/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-and-vb-net.aspx

EDIT: To clarify; C# yes, VB.NET if you use the right keywords.